# Is there a way to have nginx route ssl requests to 443 to two different apps?

Tags: nginx

I need to set up nginx so that requests via SSL to port 443 are routed to Rails Application A or Application B (say a PHP app) depending on the request path. Is this even possible to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and depends on how is your backend applications handled. You need to use `location` to match request path and route request to appropriate backend with `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass` etc.

Example:

```
server {
  listen               443;
  ssl                  on;

  location /appa/ {
    proxy_pass http://appa_backend/;
  }

  location /appb/ {
    proxy_pass http://appb_backend/;
  }
}
```